# Android listactivity, baseadapter - imageView

Tags: android, imageview, listactivity, baseadapter

I have a `ListActivity`, where I need to show a image and text in every row.

The `event.xml` layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="30px"
        android:layout_marginTop="2px" android:layout_marginRight="2px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2px" android:id="@+id/logoImage">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="15px"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity looks like this:

```
 public class Activity extends ListActivity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        dba=new DatabaseAdapter(this);

        dba.open();

        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.addHeaderView(header);

        fillOnStart();
    }

    private void fillOnStart(){
        ArrayList<Title> temp = dba.returnTitle();    // this works

        ArrAdapter notes = new ArrAdapter(this, temp);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Size: " +notes.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             
        //because this show good size

        setListAdapter(notes);             
        }
```

and my adapter looks like this:

```
 private class ArrAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<Title> lista;

        public ArrAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Title> list){
            mContext = c;
            this.lista =list;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return lista.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //  ViewHolder vh =null;
            Title title= lista.get(position);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, parent, false);

            ImageView imlogo = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.logoImage);
            TextView textTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.title);

            imlogo.setImageResource(title.getLogo());
           textTitle.setText(title.getTit());

            return v; 
        }
    }
```

class title looks like:

```
 public class Title {

        public int id;
        public String tit;
        public Bitmap logo;
public Bitmap getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }
        ... and other setter and getter      
    }
```

and method returns Arraylist (in dba) with Title look like that:

```
   public ArrayList<Title> returnTitle(){ 
            Title t = new Title(1,"aaaaaaaaaa", BitmapFactory.decodeFile("C:\\Users\\hormon\\Desktop\\favicon.ico"));
            Title t1 = new Title(2,"assdsdsdsdaa", BitmapFactory.decodeFile("C:\\Users\\hormon\\Desktop\\icon.ico"));

            ArrayList<Title> art = new ArrayList<Title>(2);
            art.add(t);
            art.add(t1);

            return  art;
        }
```

My List activity shows me only text. What I must change to see a image with text?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it is a full and easy example of what you need.

[ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)

Comment: unless this is not help me, becouse he use a image from resources, and in my app, i get this images from server (and save it) and then i show textview and imageview in listactivity. I make this BitmapFactory.decodeFile("C:\\Users\\hormon\\Desktop\\favicon.ico") only for simplification because taking image from server work ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely with the way you are attempting to assign the Title logo property. the `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` method doesn't take a local path to your machine, it takes a path from the Android device itself. It is most common, however, to use an image resource from the app's drawable folder.

```
public ArrayList<Title> returnTitle(Context ctx){ 
    Title t1 = new Title(1, "aaaaaaaaaa", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.favicon));
    Title t2 = new Title(2, "assdsdsdsdaa", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.icon));

    ArrayList<Title> art = new ArrayList<Title>(2);
    art.add(t1);
    art.add(t2);
    return art;
}
```

And then calling that method from your activity would look like

```
private void fillOnStart(){
    ArrayList<Title> temp = dba.returnTitle(this);
    // ...
}
```

Also I don't know if you noticed but in the layout the text field's id is `title` while in the adapter it is referenced as `tytul`.

Comment: this reference is not a problem, i forget change. I can't use BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.draw....); in my databaseadapter.

Comment: Ah, generally if you have a vanilla java class, and you have functionality within that class that requires access to the context, you have to pass it in either through an instance variable, or more simply as a parameter to the method. I've amended my code above to reflect the necessary change.